# how to fix System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not contain a definition for 'item'

Tags: c#

```
((AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.item(0)).src = openPDF.FileName;
```

> Error 1   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' does not
>   contain a definition for 'item' and no extension method 'item'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

anybody know how to solve this?
thanks for your help

Comment: What makes you think that class _should_ contain an `item()` method? Do you perhaps mean to write `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]` instead?

Comment: I guess the [Item property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/333f9hk4.aspx) caused this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on [MSDN: Control.ControlCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `ControlCollection`does not have a method `item(int index)` or something like that. You access the items of a `Controlcollection` via indexer like this:

```
var item = controlCollection[idx];
```

So in your case it would look like this:

```
((AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).src = openPDF.FileName;
```